# Switch of Linear Layout not working

Tags: android, android-layout, uiswitch

[My switch in linear layout :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0Xwx.png)

[The switch suppose to be like this :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Y503.png)

These are my codes :

```
<Switch
        android:id="@+id/switch1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:checked="true"
        android:onClick="onShowMiddlePoint"
        android:text="@string/showMiddlePoint" />

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switch2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:text="@string/showEyePoints"
        android:checked="false"
        android:onClick="onShowEyePoints" />
```

Comment: Share your Whole layout.xml with question

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minWidth="280dp"
            >
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="XXX"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="YYY"
                />


        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <Switch
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <Switch
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_10"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_20"
    android:text="Demos"/>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_48"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<Switch
    android:id="@+id/simpleSwitch"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checked="true"
    android:text="switch"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_10"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textOn="On"
    android:textOff="Off"
    android:textColor="#f00"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    /><!-- black background color-->

<Switch
    android:id="@+id/simple_Switch"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checked="true"
    android:text="switch"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textOn="On"
    android:textOff="Off"
    android:textColor="#f00"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    /><!-- black background color-->
</LinearLayout>
```

i think it helps you

Comment: I cannot resolve the dimen symbol like @dimen/margin_10 . Any idea?

Here is my dimens.xml file :
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <resources>

    <!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_margin_top">10dp</dimen>

     </resources>